# SQL query with subqueries

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I try to get the count of record used in other tables but SQL return null

Here my code:

```
DBConnectionClass.Command.CommandText = 
    "SELECT COUNT(IMO) 
    FROM vessel 
    WHERE ('" + IMO + "' = 
    (SELECT IMO FROM ActOfExemption)) 
    OR ('" + IMO + "' = (SELECT IMO FROM Waybill))";
            
object SQL = DBConnectionClass.Command.ExecuteScalar();
byte Result = Convert.ToByte(SQL);
```

Same query but working and without subqueries:

```
DBConnectionClass.Command.CommandText = 
    "SELECT COUNT(IMO) 
    FROM ActOfExemption 
    WHERE IMO = '" + IMO + "'";

object SQL = DBConnectionClass.Command.ExecuteScalar();
byte Result = Convert.ToByte(SQL);

DBConnectionClass.Command.CommandText = 
    "SELECT COUNT(IMO) 
    FROM Waybill 
    WHERE IMO = '" + IMO + "'";
       
SQL = DBConnectionClass.Command.ExecuteScalar();
Result += Convert.ToByte(SQL);
```

How can I do this in one query with subqueries?

Comment: Is this [the **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Try to isolate your problem and only post the minimal sql query. The c# code is not related.

Comment: You are pretty vulnerable to SQL injection attacks here...

Comment: First get the subquery based query to work directly in mysql - by the looks of your query right now, this would not work in mysql.

Comment: Please include some source data and the expected results from that source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @maccettura Consider to change the code as it is prone to SQL Injection.
It seems like, you are trying to get IMO from vessel where IMO exists in ActOfExemption or in WAybill. If so, you can change your query from

`DBConnectionClass.Command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(IMO) FROM vessel 
    WHERE ('" + IMO + "' = (SELECT IMO FROM ActOfExemption)) OR ('" + IMO + "' = (SELECT IMO FROM Waybill))";`

to

`DBConnectionClass.Command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(IMO) FROM vessel 
    WHERE ('" + IMO + "' IN (SELECT IMO FROM ActOfExemption)) OR ('" + IMO + "' IN (SELECT IMO FROM Waybill))";`

Also this is not the effective way to do that. You can actually do a left join your vessel table with **ActOfExemption** and left join with **Waybill** and consider rows where IMO is `NOT NULL` on those **two** tables.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct.  If the value of the C# variable IMO is found in either ActOfExemption or Waybill (or both), this query will return the count of rows in the vessel table.  If the value is found in neither ActOfExemption nor Waybill, it will return 0.

Comment: In the nicest possible way, this is not the answer, please see alternative answer by dougp. This would be my preferred option of the answers offered so far.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be about the SQL, so I'll ignore the apparent problems with the C# code...

Assuming the value of the C# variable IMO is "abc", the SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT 
(
  SELECT COUNT(v.IMO)
  FROM vessel v
    INNER JOIN ActOfExemption a on a.IMO = v.IMO
  WHERE v.IMO = 'abc'
) +  
(
  SELECT COUNT(v.IMO)
  FROM vessel v
    INNER JOIN Waybill W on W.IMO = v.IMO
  WHERE v.IMO = 'abc'
)
```

But this may lead to counting the same vessel record twice.

Comment: Such as SQL is, there are a number of ways to achieve the result... This however, is a good answer to the question asked.